# Redirect with htaccess for specific URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect both `/` and `/index.php?route=common/home` to `/categories`

How can I do this using htaccess? I've allready tried

```
Redirect / /categories
Redirect /index.php?route=common/home /categories
```

My currently active Rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: And what happend with that implementation you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /categories [R,L,QSD]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /categories [R,L]
```

This uses the more flexible rewriting module. Which has to be loaded and activated for that location inside your http server, obviously.

The best place to implement such rules is inside the central http server's host configuration. You can use a *distributed* configuration file instead (".htaccess"), but that comes with a few disadvantages. If you do then take care to enable that feature (read about the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation) and make sure the file is readable for the http server process and located inside the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

Comment: The redirect from the base works now but not from route=common/home

Comment: The rule implements exactly what you ask. So either what you ask is not the actual situation you have or there is some other effect that interferes here. Do you have any other rewriting rule in place? What are they?

Comment: I've added all rewrite rules from my htaccess to the question above.

Comment: @MarvinKlein Oh, I do have to apologize! I fixed the answer. It obviously has to be `%{QUERY_STRING}`, not `${QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: @MarvinKlein A general remark here, please understand it as constructive suggestion: you should never rely on just copying something from here or elsewhere in the internet without analyzing and understanding it. You could and should easily have spotted that obvious typo in the answer yourself if you would have taken a short glimpse into the documentation of the tools you are trying to use, here the rewriting module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html As typical for OpenSource it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Comment: We are almost there. It does the redirecting now but it appends the `route=` stuff

Comment: @MarvinKlein I added the `QSD` flag to the answer. Again: take a look at the documentation above. I posted the link two comments above.